# Plot a Scatter Plot from a List in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, plot, scatter-plot

I am fairly new to R so please excuse this maybe very basic question.

I have a list of floats like below:

```
my_list
[1] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.6666667 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.6666667 0.6666667 1.0000000
```

I want to have a scatter plot with the index on the x axis and the value of each index on the y axis.
My thought now is to convert this into a data frame with value of each element as one column and index in the other column. However, I am not even sure how to do that.

I appreciate any help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are tons of parameters to tweak. Type `?plot` to bring up a help page

```
plot(my_list)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! When i do plot(my_list), I get the following error: Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'. Sorry if this is a basic question, i'm very new to R.

Comment: it depends on the structure of your data. Share the output of `dput(my_list)` and we can see exactly what we're working with

Comment: Hi, the dput(my_list) is list(1, 1, 1, 0.666666666666667, 1, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
    1)

Comment: you can change the object type of you list to a vector, it is more appropriate than having numbers in a list. you can use `my_list <- unlist(my_list)`. Afterwards you will be able to use `plot` as above

Answer (score 1):

Having `my_list` already defined, we just create an index by using the `length()` function of my_list, and then make a simple plot.

```
index<- 1:length(my_list)
plot(index, my_list)
```

[image]

Comment: the default behaviour of `plot` is to use the index if only one vector is provided. No need to create your own index.

Comment: Good to know, Thanks